# Robospice offline task. Do I need cache?

Tags: android, caching, robospice

In my application i have to zip some files and then send them to amazon server. I decided to use Robospice for this task. Do i need cache for this? If so, how should I implement it or else how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the [`com.octo.android.robospice.SpiceManager#execute(com.octo.android.robospice.request.SpiceRequest<T>, com.octo.android.robospice.request.listener.RequestListener<T>)`](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/blob/release/robospice-core-parent/robospice/src/main/java/com/octo/android/robospice/SpiceManager.java#L442) method, which doesn't utilize the cache.
For the initialization of RoboSpice, although your request does not seem to be offline, you can check the [offline sample on GitHub](https://github.com/octo-online/RoboSpice-samples/tree/master/robospice-sample-core-offline), specifically the [SampleOfflineSpiceService class](https://github.com/octo-online/RoboSpice-samples/blob/master/robospice-sample-core-offline/src/com/octo/android/robospice/sample/offline/SampleOfflineSpiceService.java).

Comment: Thanks, I must have overlooked that class in spice offline sample. I implemented it and now everythings fine. :)